# Error updating field in ms access 2007

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have a form on which there are two subforms.In the afterUpdate() event of combobox of subform1 I want a combobox of subform to get updated with the same value and vice versa.Subform2 depends upon subform2 for its field called ID.As in if I create a new record on subform1 then the subform2 displays data based on records in subform1.New entries can be made in subform1 and modification in the data on subform2 can be made for the records in subform1.This is because subform1 brings data from the base table and subform2 gets related data from some other related tables also.
Everything runs fine if Ihave to update the comboboxes in the 2 subforms for an existing record.However,if I add a new record in subform1,then it throws error "you cannot assign a value to this object" in the afterupdate event of the combobox of subform1.Now if I navigate to subform2 and come back to subform1 and change the value of combobox, it gets updated and throws no error.
The comboboxes in both the forms have same rowsource.

Please suggest me some methods which I can use to avoid this problem.

Comment: Please post the *concise* code that you've written so far.

Comment: I suspect you need to requery subform2 from subform1 in the After Insert event.

Comment: I am refreshing the form and using the following code in the afterupdate event of the comboboxes and same for the form_current() event. Forms![frmiiindex]![sfrmIIINDEXDATALISTNUM].Form.cboPID = Me.[P_ID] Forms![frmiiindex]![sfrmIIINDEXDATA].Form.Refresh

Comment: Not refresh, requery. There is a big difference.

Comment: I tried requery.It's still not working.

Comment: There's one improvement.When I use requery then the combobox1 doesn't get updated and immediately gets cleared in the first attempt.This at least ensures that users would know that combobox1 is empty before navigating to any other form.